# JavaScript Canvas Text Ratio

Tags: javascript, canvas, aspect-ratio, text-size

i have a fixed sized Canvas (850x400px) and when I'm adding text to this canvas, its scaled up in a weird way, and I don't know why.

If I do not set the canvas to a specific height/width, the text appears normal, why is that?

```
export function addText() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // 850x400px
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var y = 1 * 20 + 20;

  var text = {
    text: "ABC",
    x: 20,
    y: y
  };

  ctx.font = "40px consolas";
  text.width = ctx.measureText(text.text).width;
  text.height = 80;
  ctx.fillText(text.text, text.x, text.y);
}
```

This is what the text in the canvas field will look like:

[image]

How can I insert text that is scaled just like normal 40px font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not specified the width and height of the canvas HTML element itself, try:

```js
addText();

function addText() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // 850x400px
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var y = 1 * 20 + 20;

  var text = {
    text: "ABC",
    x: 20,
    y: y
  };

  ctx.font = "40px consolas";
  text.width = ctx.measureText(text.text).width;
  text.height = 80;
  ctx.fillText(text.text, text.x, text.y);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="850" height="400" style="background: red"></canvas>
```

**Update**

Another option is to set the width and height programmatically, this will prevent the zooming:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
```

I used the window width and height, but any other element will do it.

Comment: well its set to width: 100% and height: 100%, which is 450x850 in my case.

Comment: If you set it in a css class, that could be the cause of the problem

Comment: i already solved this issue, i came up with almost the same solution:    


`ctx.canvas.width = $('#imageFrame').width();` and 
    `ctx.canvas.height = $('#imageFrame').height();`

frame is the parent element.